# ffmpeg avformat_open_input with custom stream object

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to write a custom `SoundFileReader` for SFML using ffmpeg's libraries. The only thing I have available to use with avcodec and avformat is the class `InputStream` below which is part of SFML. I've looked at `avformat_open_input` and `AVIOContext` and I learned how to use custom stream with a buffer but how do I create an `AVIOContext` that works with the custom read, seek, and lseek functions?

```
class InputStream {
    int64_t getSize()
    int64_t read(void* data, int64_t size);
    int64_t seek(int64_t position);
    int64_t tell(); // Gets the stream position
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a set of callback functions and then pass a pointers to these callbacks and to opaque param to `avio_alloc_context`. Notice that these callbacks must not throw.

```c++
/// <summary>
/// Reads up to buffer_capacity_bytes_count bytes into supplied buffer.
/// Basically should work like ::read C method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="opaque">
/// Opaque pointer to reader instance. Passing nullptr is not allowed.
/// </param>
/// <param name="p_buffer">
/// Pointer to data buffer. Passing nullptr is not allowed.
/// </param>
/// <param name="buffer_capacity_bytes_count">
/// Size of the buffer pointed to by p_buffer, in bytes.
/// Passing value less than or equal to 0 is not allowed.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// Non negative values containing amount of bytes actually read. 0 if EOF has been reached.
/// -1 if an error occurred.
/// </returns>
static auto
Read(void * const opaque, uint8_t * const p_buffer, int const buffer_capacity_bytes_count) noexcept
{
    int result{-1};
    if(opaque && p_buffer && (0 <= buffer_capacity_bytes_count))
    {
        auto & stream{*reinterpret_cast< InputStream * >(opaque)};
        try
        {
            auto const read_result{stream.read(p_buffer, buffer_capacity_bytes_count)};
            if((0 <= read_result) && (read_result <= buffer_capacity_bytes_count))
            {
                result = read_result;
            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            // print error or something
        }
    }
    return(result);
}

/// <summary>
/// Changes file pointer position or retrieves file size.
/// Basically should work like ::lseek and ::fstat C methods.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="opaque">
/// Opaque pointer to reader instance. Passing nullptr is not allowed.
/// </param>
/// <param name="pos">
/// Target offset. When retrieving file size this should be 0.
/// </param>
/// <param name="whence">
/// Flag indicating operation. Valid values are SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END (as in C library),
/// AVSEEK_SIZE and optional AVSEEK_FORCE bit.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// Non-negative values containing offset of the file pointer or file size in bytes.
/// Negative values if an error occurred.
/// </returns>
static auto
Seek(void * const opaque, int64_t const pos, int const whence) noexcept
{
    int64_t result{AVERROR(EBADF)};
    if(opaque)
    {
        auto & stream{*reinterpret_cast< InputStream * >(opaque)};
        try
        {
            auto const action{whence & (SEEK_SET | SEEK_CUR | SEEK_END | AVSEEK_SIZE)};
            auto const forced{0 != (whence & AVSEEK_FORCE)}; // can be ignored
            switch(action)
            {
                case SEEK_SET:
                case SEEK_CUR:
                case SEEK_END:
                {
                    // TODO perform seek...
                    break;
                }
                case AVSEEK_SIZE:
                {
                    result = stream.getSize();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            // print error or something
        }
    }
    return(result);
}

...

InputStream stream;
auto const opaque{reinterpret_cast< void * >(::std::addressof(stream))};
auto p_io_context
{
    ::avio_alloc_context
    (
        static_cast< unsigned char * >(p_buffer) // ownership is not transferred
    ,   buffer_size
    ,   0 // 0 if openning for reading, 1 if openning for writing
    ,   opaque
    ,   &Read
    ,   nullptr // write callback function, not used if we open for reading
    ,   &Seek
    )
};
```

Comment: Well I'm glad I didn't post my answer I got because this actually has a fix for an issue I was just encountering with m4a files. The `AVSEEK_SIZE` whence option fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: In the case of Read, and it's streaming from an external source, what should it return of there is no data available?  Or should it just block?

Comment: @jpwkeeper 0 should be returned only if all the data has been read. If some data may become available in the future then you should just block until it arrives.